# Not able to set content length for ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, streamingresponsebody

I'm trying to download a zip file in spring boot. Using `HttpServletResponse` output stream. We will be reading a file from local, zip it, inside `StreamingResponseBody` and add it in the return statement of `ResponseEntity.body(StreamingResponseBody)`. We require content length to show progress bar in UI. We can get `zipEntry.getCompressedSize()` for the content length. But as soon as the zip file is written spring boot sending response headers to UI and I'll be getting content length only after I close zipoutputstream. Because of this I'm getting 0 as content length as a header in UI.
Can you please help me to properly add content length to response headers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Zip to filesystem. Close stream, determine size, then stream to client. If you really want you need an intermediate step.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum we are wrapping the zip similar to https://medium.com/swlh/streaming-data-with-spring-boot-restful-web-service-87522511c071 using lamda. Without filesystem is it possible to set content length.

Comment: You would need to store it in memory in a byte[] or `ByteArrayOutputStream` however that is really memory intensive and might lead to OOM.

Comment: If you are using the code from the link, you are actually using a file system (as a `File` is just that, a resource on the filesystem).